# xUnit doens't support async test?

Tags: c#, .net, xunit

I read that xUnit V2.4.1 support async test (I added nuget packages `xunit.runner.visualstudio` and `xunit.runner.console` to my Visual Studio 2015 project.). So I created the following tests.

```
[Fact]
public async Task SearchItemSqlRepositoryModel_Reset()
{
     await _searchItemSqlRepository.GetSearchItems(....);
}
```

However, `Run Test` shows "No tests found to run"?

I tried to change the `Task` to `void` and it still doesn't work.

```
[Fact]
public async void SearchItemSqlRepositoryModel_Reset()
```

However, the synchronous version works.

```
[Fact]
public void SearchItemSqlRepositoryModel_Reset0()
{
    _searchItemSqlRepository.GetSearchItems(....).Wait();
}
```

Comment: It's marked with `[Fact]`

Comment: which version of xUnit are you on?

Comment: Is this in a part of a project that already has xUnit tests in it? What you have should be enough for it to work. You may want to try a clean and rebuild or restarting your IDE.

Comment: @RandomUs1r, V2.4.1

Comment: @JonathonChase, I created a xUnit test project before I changed the method to async.

Comment: Can you confirm that if you make it non async it appears?

Comment: @Dave, yes, the synchronous version works. I've updated the question.

Comment: What are your running the tests with, resharper test runner or something else? Are you using .net core or framework? My .net core project runs async tests with xunit 2.3.1 (netcoreapp2.1) using resharper test runner.

Comment: @CRice `xunit.runner.visualstudio`. I also installed nuget package of `xunit.runner.console`.

Comment: Perhaps try with resharper test runner - if that works you know its your runner and if not its your test code.

Comment: @CRice I don't have resharper....

Comment: @ca9163d9 have you tried adding an assertion?

Comment: @RandomUs1r I added `Assert.True(1 == 1);` at the end of the async test method and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a xUnit runner bug.

- Right-clicking in the editor and then clicking `Run Tests` will not run these async tests.
- However, clicking `Run All` in the Test Explorer will work. But it still will not show the green check icon in front of the test methods. It will show the green check icon in the "Test Explorer" though.

Answer (score 0):

If you change "async Task" to "async void" your tests will run. In fact this behaviour (kind of) is by design. See the issue below:

https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1405

Comment: I tried and it didn't run by right-clicking. See my answer for the details.